# Authentication against local AD in the Angular application

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I've been developing an Angular app with .NET Core backend (services). The task is to enable an integrated authentication, i.e. make it work with the local user seamlessly, so I login to my (connected to a local AD) machine once and the web application lets me in without the necessity to login a second time. We've been working with Identity Server 4 and intended to implement this scenario using it.

There is a little documentation on the official website concerning the Windows Authentication (e.g. against Active directory): http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/windows.html but it doesn't explain much. As per my info, to make this scenario work the browser utilizes either Kerberos or NTLM. Neither of them is mentioned in the IS4 docs. I'm lacking the understanding of how the local credentials are getting picked up and how IS4 'knows' the user belongs to AD? How I can make sure only the users from a specific domain have access to my app?

I found some working stuff here https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreWindowsAuth but questions remain the same. Even though I was able to get to the app with my local account I don't understand the flow.

I expect the user utilizing the app in the local network to log-in to the app without entering the login/password (once he's already logged in to the Windows). Is this something achievable?

Comment: I just updated my asnwer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identity Server is intended to serve as an Identity Provider, if you need to talk with your AD you should see the Federation Gateway architecture they propose using the IAuthenticationSchemeProvider. Where Identity Server acts as an endpoint and talks with your AD.

This is the link: [Federation Gateway](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/ui/federation/)

You have the control to programmatically reach your AD and pass the correct credentials to get the authentication. That step should be done in your Identity Server. After you get authenticated you should get redirected to your application again.
About your last question, the answer is yes, if you have your website hosted on an intranet and you have the access to your AD, you don't need to capture your credentials as user input, you can programmatically reach the AD as I said.

Bellow is the code I use to connect with my active directory

On the ExternalController class, you get when you use IdentityServer, you have this:(I don't remember at the top of my head how much I changed from the original code, but you should get the idea)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// initiate roundtrip to external authentication provider
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Challenge(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) returnUrl = "~/";

        // validate returnUrl - either it is a valid OIDC URL or back to a local page
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) == false && _interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(returnUrl) == false)
        {
            // user might have clicked on a malicious link - should be logged
            throw new Exception("invalid return URL");
        }

        if (AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName == provider)
        {
            // windows authentication needs special handling
            return await ProcessWindowsLoginAsync(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            // start challenge and roundtrip the return URL and scheme 
            var props = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(Callback)),
                Items =
                {
                    { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
                    { "scheme", provider },
                }
            };

            return Challenge(props, provider);
        }
    }

private async Task<IActionResult> ProcessWindowsLoginAsync(string returnUrl)
        {
            // see if windows auth has already been requested and succeeded
            var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName);
            if (result?.Principal is WindowsPrincipal wp)
            {
                // we will issue the external cookie and then redirect the
                // user back to the external callback, in essence, testing windows
                // auth the same as any other external authentication mechanism
                var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
                {
                    RedirectUri = Url.Action("Callback"),
                    Items =
                    {
                        { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
                        { "scheme", AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName },
                    }
                };

                var id = new ClaimsIdentity(AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName);
                id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, wp.Identity.Name));
                id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, wp.Identity.Name));

                // add the groups as claims -- be careful if the number of groups is too large
                if (AccountOptions.IncludeWindowsGroups)
                {
                    var wi = wp.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
                    var groups = wi.Groups.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
                    var roles = groups.Select(x => new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, x.Value));
                    id.AddClaims(roles);
                }

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                    IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
                    new ClaimsPrincipal(id),
                    props);
                return Redirect(props.RedirectUri);
            }
            else
            {
                // trigger windows auth
                // since windows auth don't support the redirect uri,
                // this URL is re-triggered when we call challenge
                return Challenge(AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName);
            }
        }
```

If you want to use Azure AD, I would recommend you to read this article:
https://damienbod.com/2019/05/17/updating-microsoft-account-logins-in-asp-net-core-with-openid-connect-and-azure-active-directory/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you want, but I would use the `Active Directory Federation Services` to configure an `OAuth2 endpoint` and obtain the user token in the .Net Core Web App.

Isn't NTLM authentication support limited on non Microsoft browsers?

OAuth2 have the advantage of using only standard technologies.

Comment: it makes sense, I was thinking on this option, although, how does it help to achieve a seamless login experience? To clarify, the scenario you're talking about would be the following:
*ADFS plays the role of STS (i.e. security token service)
*when the user goes to an app, the backend sends the auth request
*the request is being verified by the ADFS
*it sends the token back once the identity is confirmed
*user is authenticated
Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to have 2 instances of the app deployed. 
The first one is configured to use Windows Authentication and the other one uses IS4.

ex:
[yoursite.internal.com](http://yoursite.internal.com)

[yoursite.com](http://yoursite.com)

Your local DNS should redirect traffic internally from yoursite.com to yoursite.internal.com

yoursite.internal.com will be the one configured to use AD authentication. You  should have a flag in your appsettings.json to indicate if this instance is a AD auth or IS4 auth.

The downside of this solution is that you have to deploy 2 instances

Comment: Identity Server solves that issue for you, in your case you need to involve the Infrastructure team to fix the problem and deploy the app at the level of the DNS a programmatically base on a key on the appsettings do one thing or the other. In my opinion, you should program that feature you describe on Identity server and that should be transparent for the user

Comment: hi @Zinov, thanks for the answer. About the Federation Gateway approach... is there any samples around (.net core) involving this scenario? Is this solution containerizable?

Comment: @Zinov with identity server, you still have the home realm discovery and the user will have to choose weather they want to authenticate using username and password or using AD. This is an extra step unless you mean the configuration should be done on IS4 to detect internal users and authenticate them automatically which is the same as the solution suggested but a different method

Comment: If you have Identity server, why no centralize all the authentication in just one place? That is the idea with id4, but answering your question you are right, your solution is right as well but requires more configuration effort.